# Laravel site suddenly not working, and I need help interpreting error messages

Tags: php, laragon

I have a Laravel project which was working up to a few days ago, but now isn't.  I think it's a config problem, but I am far from being knowledgeable about such things.  Here's what I do know:

The project is still running correctly on our server.  Another developer has a working local copy on his PC.  It's the local copy on my PC that isn't working.

When I try to run the local site from Laragon, I get this error message:

> This page isn’t working right now
>
> site.test can't currently handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

The Laragon error logs don't contain anything that I can decipher as useful information.  Windows Event Viewer gives me this error:

> The description for Event ID 4 from source PHP-7.4.30 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> php[127824]
> PHP Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame (C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.54-win64-VS16\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/laragon/bin/apache/httpd-2.4.54-win64-VS16)
>
> The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table

The project uses PHP v 7.4.30 and MySQL for a database.

What does this error mean?  How do I fix it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have deleted and recreated the project, and also uninstalled and reinstalled Laragon.  Neither made any difference.  The site simply will not load.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How?  I don't know what the problem is.  I don't know what might be causing it.  I don't get a syntax error that points to a specific line of code, so I don't even know where the error is occurring in all the thousands of lines of code or dozens of different modules used by Laravel.  I just get the errors I described in my original post.  The only other fact I can give is that it doesn't happen on all computers, or even all Windows-based computers.  My coworker has a computer that is almost identical to mine, but I'm getting this error and he isn't.